# How to make AWS Stepfunctions/ECS schedule tasks only when resources are available

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

I am using ECS/EC2 to run Stepfunction (Standard type) tasks

I am using an API to trigger the StepFunction execution, So sometimes I have a peek more thyan the capacity of the ECS cluster, So I frequently get errors like this:

```
[{"Arn":"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:432214534264:container-instance/192a09715eea48828b798600b5c67532","Reason":"RESOURCE:GPU"}] (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AmazonECS.Unknown; Request ID: d33c3afa-d158-45f4-83f4-2567efb53017; Proxy: null)
```

Which means I do not have enough GPU (Sometimes MEMORY) to run more tasks.

So, How to configure the StepFunction and/or the ECS cluster to only schedule tasks if its resources are available.

I tried PlacementConstraints and PlacementStrategies, but they are fit for this, as these are guides to distribute tasks when resources are enough, not to pause new task creation till resources are available

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to have enough resources on ECS/EC2 cluster (scale out) so that StepFunction can trigger a task and ECS can fulfill that request? Or you want step function to stop/go in wait till resources are available (without scale out)?

Comment: yes, I want a way to make Stepfunction or the ECS cluster stop spawning tasks till resources are available. ECS cluster has all the info needed for that, instead of sending an error I want it to wait till the required resources are available